# How to get total transactions on the network with RPC

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-cli, full-node

I have seen no concrete answer to this question anywhere.
I assume it is possible to get the total number of successful transactions on the bitcoin network using bitcoin-cli command because most explorers provide this information.
How can i get this information from a fully synced node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure this is not exposed by the RPC API.

You could parse `debug.log` and look for lines like:

```
2019-08-20T12:17:58Z UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000000e6c402b311740e21f79a42ed84ecf69a3ae4fe88ce882 height=590956 version=0x20000000 log2_work=90.9855 tx=446914655 date='2019-08-20T12:17:55Z' progress=1.000000 cache=277.1MiB(321228txo)
```

Where `tx=num` gives the total transaction count. I reckon that most explorers maintain a separate database of the transactions, and simply run a query against that instead of pulling data like this from a node or log.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use the [`getblockstats`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/blockchain/getblockstats/) command to get the number of transactions (not including the coinbase transaction) for a specific block (by height/hash). E.g.

```
$ getblockstats 500000 '["txs"]'

{
  "txs": 2701
}
```

Then, iterate through all of the blocks to get the total for all blocks.