# How many TXO have been created in total?

Tags: utxo, output

I've seen some statistical data about the Bitcoin UTXO number (around 61M currently). I was wondering how many TXOs (including spent and unspent) there were in the complete history of Bitcoin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get total transactions on the network with RPC](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/89826/how-to-get-total-transactions-on-the-network-with-rpc)

Comment: @JBaczuk: These two questions are related but different in that the linked question is asking for the total __transaction count__ and this one here is asking about the total __transaction output count__. Voting to leave open.